# Conteúdo passa acima do "header" ao rolar página;

Tags: css

Tenho um *header* fixo, e logo abaixo tenho uma *section*, ai que esta o problema, ao rolar a página o conteúdo da *section*, passa por cima do conteúdo do *header*, e a minha intenção era que ele passasse abaixo do *header*, sumindo o conteúdo que for passando.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #009688;
  height: 65px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0
}
.container-logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
}
.container-logo span {
  display: none;
}
.container-menu {
  height: 60px;
  width: 64%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.container-menu nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.container-menu nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.container-menu nav ul li a {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #EDEDED;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.container-menu > nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: #EDEDED;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container-menu > nav ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.container-menu > nav ul li a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.menu-icon {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  /*1366 px */
  height: 580px;
  position: relative;
  top: 65.5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.apresentation {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  /* 1366 px */
  position: relative;
}
.apresentation h1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  color: #009688;
  text-shadow: #EDEDED 1px -1px 2px, #EDEDED -1px 1px 2px, #EDEDED 1px 1px 2px, #EDEDED -1px -1px 2px;
}
.contact {
  width: 100%;
  height: 580px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-logo">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <span><a href="#"><img src="img/menu.svg" alt="Menu"></a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container-menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="img/home.svg">Início</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="img/about.svg">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="img/code.svg">Trabalhos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="img/mail.svg">Contato</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="main">
  <div class="apresentation">
    <h1>Olá! Seja bem vindo ao meu espaço.</h1>
    <h2>Sou estudante de sistemas de informação!!</h2>

  </div>
</section>

<section class="contact">
  <form>
    <fieldset>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

Notem que ao rolar a pagina o conteúdo passa acima do *header*.

Comment: É como na resposta do @Chun, você precisa usar o atributo `z-index`. Por padrão o próximo elemento fica afrente do elemento anterior, mesmo tendo o mesmo `z-index`, mas você pode ordena-los com essa propriedade.

Comment: É isso mesmo quando maior o número do   z-index mais a frente dos demais elementos ele estará.

Answer (score 2):

Tens que adicionar um `z-index` ao header para que este problema não aconteça. Por exemplo:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #009688;
    height: 65px;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9; /* Adiciona esta propriedade */
}
```

Exemplo no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kp5qkxf7/

### Sobre o `z-index`

A propriedade `z-index` determina o "**nível de empilhamento**" de um elemento HTML. O "nível de empilhamento" - Refere-se à posição do elemento, no eixo Z (em oposição ao eixo X ou eixo Y). Um valor `z-index` positivo superior a > `0`, significa que o elemento estará mais próximo do topo, na ordem de empilhamento. Esta ordem de empilhamento ocorre perpendicularmente à tela (ou janela de exibição).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cara, Muito obrigado mesmo, deu certo aqui... Irei dar uma estudada sobre esse x-index Obrigado

Comment: De nada @YutoSan :) Não existe melhor maneira de dizer obrigado no Stack Overflow do que selecionar uma resposta como correcta ou votar positivamente nela =)

Comment: Cara, eu nunca tinha vista esta propriedade. Já fiz até curso de html + css + javascript + php + MySQL , etc.. E nunca vi esse conteúdo !